# How can I calculate the average and then the percentage increase in two TimeSpan values in a list

Tags: c#

I have an object that has as properties two TimeSpan values.

```
public class TestTimes
{
    public TimeSpan first_time { get; set; }        
    public TimeSpan second_time { get; set; }
}
```

And its in a list..so

```
List<TestTimes> lst_times = new List<TestTimes>();
```

So here is my question.

I want to calculate the average of all of TimeSpans for each property in the list(first_time and second_time) so that I get that average....and then I want to calculate the percentage difference from first_time to second_time.  meaning if I assume first_time is a baseline...the second_time value is + or - percentage faster. (negative faster equating slower).

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to solve the problem.  I don't know if this is the most efficient...but it gets the job done.

If anyone knows of a more efficient way feel free to comment.

```
        long average_tspan_first_time = Convert.ToInt64(lst_results.Average(t => t.first_time.Ticks));
        TimeSpan avg_first_time = new TimeSpan(average_tspan_first_time);
        long average_tspan_second_time = Convert.ToInt64(lst_results.Average(t => t.second_time.Ticks));
        TimeSpan avg_second_time = new TimeSpan(average_tspan_second_time);

        double p_change = ((double)average_tspan_second_time - (double)average_tspan_first_time) / (double)average_tspan_first_time * 100;
```